# Invoke webrequest fails to fetch website data even though works in all browsers

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

Powershell: The invoke-webrequest is not working for me for a particular site. Tried many things like setting TLS settings etc. But still fails.
One unique thing is it works for first request, post then it fails for 15mins but such is not the case when browsing the site via browser. Can anyone help me please

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_turnapr2020.htm'
```

For the next request it waits forever then goes timeout. But in browser that is not the case(in IE, chrome)

[Timeout error image. First request works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhAWY.png)

Comment: If it works on 1st try and then it doesn't, you are likely triggering an anti-scrape mechanism. Does the data publisher offer XML api or the like, which is intended to use with automation?

Comment: Thanks for that. No api(outside of my org, so can't request too).
But it works via browser(multiple refreshes). so how to accomplish that via powershell?

Comment: @vonPryz thanks for that, i did have a little check on anti-scrape mechanism. And to try out i added headers(copied from browser) and then it started working without failures. (help for others, from developer tools of browser > copy > copy as powershell) then extract the headers hashtable
Problem Solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because of website's anti-scrape mechanism. To Bypass that we need to make it feel like a user request via browser. For this current problem with this website., solution was to include headers in the Invoke-WebRequest.
You can take copy of request headers via Chrome Developer Tools > Network tab > (right click url) > Copy > copy as powershell.
Then paste that & take the hashtable of headers.(you can then remove cookies section).