# .Net and powershell download json very slow

Tags: windows, powershell

Hello i have the following scenario. I want to download a json file with a list of objects using my api and an bearer token for authorization.

The problem is, i tried it in C# WinForms using WebClient, HttpRequest, HttpClient or as Powershell script. I tried .Net 6 and 7. The downloads are very slow. It needs between 10 and 20 seconds.

When i use Java, Postman or my Browser, the request needs under one second.

What is the problem? Why its so very slow?

Here is my Powershell script.

```
$token = "Token"

#Fetch Games
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://DOMAIN/api/games" -Headers $headers
Write-Host "Select an item:"
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $response.Count; $i++) {
    Write-Host "$i. $($response[$i].title)"
}
$userSelection = Read-Host "Enter the number of the item you want to select"
```

I tried to reinstall my PC but it not helpfull

Comment: How large is the document? ```Invoke-RestMethod``` downloads the json and then parses it - as a test, you could use ```Invoke-WebRequest``` and see how the timings compare for just the download without the parsing. It might not help with your script, but it may explain the timings…

Comment: "I tried to reinstall my PC but it not helpfull" - This seems like a quite premature and extreme troubleshooting step.

Comment: Try to set: `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`. I have also seen sites that slow down as they detect a script (can't find it back).

Comment: @mclayton i adding breakpoints and outputs before parsing, its the same problem.

Comment: @iRon not differences

Comment: Not sure if it applies: [Invoke webrequest fails to fetch website data even though works in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61225983/1701026)

Comment: @iRon also not working

Comment: That's a pretty, unless you come up with more details or a way to reproduce this, I am afraid it end here.